# Convert comma to dot when the number is lower then 1

Tags: php, mysql

I found one problem with converting number with comma to dot if the number is lower then 1. If the number is higher then 1 everything is OK.

I use this Replace script:

```
$price = str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['PRICE']);
```

- if I post `0.5` - everything is OK
- if I post `0,5` (with comma) then I receive this error:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in....

The field PRICE is DOUBLE format.

All other numbers higher then 1 are accepted with comma.

Comment: You probably aren't escaping or quoting the content.  Escape and quote it.  And for goodness' sake, *validate* user input.

Comment: where is you mysql_query line?

Comment: @Tufan `mysql_`!!?? No! `PDO::`

Comment: @ColeJohnson: If only.  :P  The error message makes it clear that he's using that ancient, noobish, *deprecated* mysql_ crap.  -0.49 for that alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_price = str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['PRICE']); // convert to applicable format
$PRICE = is_numeric($_price) ? (float)$_price : null; // for consistency that there will be smth. similar to number, but not sneaky piece of script from kind user
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [settype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) before running the SQL query.

```
$PRICE = str_replace(",", ".", $_POST['PRICE']);    
settype($PRICE, 'float');
```